# Why is ViewDidLoad Called if I cancel TouchID prompt

Tags: objective-c

When I press 'Cancel' on a TouchID prompt, the prompt disappears and the instantly reappears...    My biometrics method is called inside ViewDidLoad, I added an NSLog inside ViewDidLoad and it is getting called when I dismiss the TouchID dialog.  I've looked and tried several examples of how to implement TouchID, but all result in the same outcome.

```
  - (void)useBiometrics{
        LAContext* context = [[LAContext alloc] init];
        NSError* error = nil;
        NSString* result = @"Use Touch ID to login";


        if ([context canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&error]) {

            [context evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics localizedReason:result reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                if (success) {

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


                        UIStoryboard *storyboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
                        LoginViewController *loginController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerROOTIdentifier"];
                        [self.navigationController pushViewController:loginController animated:NO];

                        FROM_LOGIN = YES;

                        NEEDS_LOGIN = FALSE;
                    });
                }
                else
                {

                    switch (error.code) {
                        case LAErrorSystemCancel:
                        {

                            break;
                        }
                        case LAErrorUserCancel:
                        {
                            NSLog(@"TouchID canceled");
                            break;
                        }
                        case LAErrorAuthenticationFailed:
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        case LAErrorPasscodeNotSet:
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        case LAErrorBiometryNotAvailable:
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        case LAErrorBiometryNotEnrolled:
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        case LAErrorUserFallback:
                        {
                            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

                            }];
                            break;
                        }
                        default:
                        {
                            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                            }];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }];
        }
        else
        {
            switch (error.code) {
                case LAErrorBiometryNotEnrolled:
                {
                    break;
                }
                case LAErrorPasscodeNotSet:
                {
                    NSLog(@"A passcode has not been set");
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    NSLog(@"TouchID not available");
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Did "TouchID canceled" being logged when you press cancel?

Comment: @matt  let me break it down for you!  "biometrics method" is useBiometrics..   I have stated  all the places that the 'useBiometrics' method is called..     I'm only loading  ViewControllerROOTIdentifier once the user has authenticated successfully, it's also pretty obvious that I'm in the 'loginController'.

Comment: @GeneCode yes the action is acknowledged